# How to avoid memory blow up when using vstack on multiple astropy tables

Tags: python, astropy

I need to build a large `astropy` table by merging many smaller tables. I am using `vstack` repeatedly as `bigTable = vstack([bigTable, smallTable])` but the memory is blowing up very fast.
Each individual table is typically 9 columns times ~1000 lines and after 5 or 6 iterations the memory is  >100 GB

Comment: What is the expected memory size of your big table? Do all your tables fit in memory (both the small ones and the stacked one)? Then just passing all small tables at once should be efficient, i.e. `bigTable = vstack([t1, t2, t3, ..., tN])`. I think calling vstack many times can never give an efficient implementation.

Comment: The most memory-efficient would probably be to pre-allocate the big table, and then to have a Python for loop to always only load a small table, fill it in the big table, one by one (and Python garbage collects the small table objects at the end of your for loop). That would require only half of the memory of having all tables in memory together, but it's more coding i.e. less efficient in terms of your coding time.

Comment: Yes I have verified that all individual tables fit in memory and are using < 1 GB

Comment: Do you have some more info? Because 9x1000 seems very little for a table; that shouldn't cause 100GB usage (not even 1GB), unless you're storing complete FITS files inside each cell. Do you have some actual code you can show? It feels as if something else is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498873/christoph) I found the solution. I just needed to vstack all the small tables at once using a list.

```
from astropy.table import Table, vstack
catList = []
for ... :
   catList.append(cat)
bigCat = vstack(catList)
```

For some reasons 'vstacking' a table with itself is very inefficient

Comment: FWIW, depending on how complicated the work is in your `for` loop you might be able to replace it with a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).